# Count number of times I fail a game in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is there any way to count the number of times the scene transitions from the game over scene to the game scene?

Doing this for implementing rewarded video ads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `UserDefaults`.

```
// GameViewController or MainScene
// when you start the game set the value to 0

UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "numberOfTries")

// GameScene
// before transitioning to the new scene, increment the value by 1 and save it

var numberOfTries = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "numberOfTries")
numberOfTries += 1
UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfTries, forKey: "numberOfTries")

// MenuScene
// get the value and compare it, if it reached the try limit, show video and reset the value

var numberOfTries = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "numberOfTries")
if numberOfTries == maxNumberOfTriesBeforeVideo {
    // show video
    numberOfTries = 0
    UserDefaults.standard.set(numberOfTries, forKey: "numberOfTries")
}
```

Comment: Aaah! Thank you so much for this!